# How to bring list of buttons when button pressed in iOS app

Tags: ios, button

I don't know what to search for or what it is called, as I am totally new. Please help me that when I press button it will show other button. We found it in lot of apps, but I don't know the name.. I attached its picture below. How can I do this in an iOS app.

[image: Options]

Comment: removed the mention of Xcode, as your question has nothing to do with the IDE and everything to do with with iOS.

Comment: That is a `UIActionSheet`. If you'd like to develop iOS apps I'd recommend you get started with the essential reading - the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is called [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

And here is a rater complex example:

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init] ;
    actionSheet.title = @"Change pincode?";
    actionSheet.delegate = self;
    actionSheet.tag = kChangePincode;

    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Chacge pincode"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove pin code"];

    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"cancel"];
    [actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:(actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 1)];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thank for this code... Also get helped from http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/simple-menus-and-messages-with-uiactionsheet.html

Answer (score 0):

Go through the [UIActionsheet.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
Do additons like this

// in .h class

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {

    ...

}


...


-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender;
```

@end

In .m

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];
}


// Handle Delegates-------------
    -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            self.label.text = @"Other Button 1 Clicked";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
            self.label.text = @"Other Button 2 Clicked";
        } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
            self.label.text = @"Cancel Button Clicked";
        }

        /**
         * OR use the following switch statement
         * 
         */
        /*
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
                break;
            case 1:
                self.label.text = @"Other Button 1 Clicked";
                break;
            case 2:
                self.label.text = @"Other Button 2 Clicked";
                break;
            case 3:
                self.label.text = @"Cancel Button Clicked";
                break;
        }
        */
    }
```